# postgresql physical replication from v9.6 to v15 support

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-15

Is postgresql physical replication from  v9.6 to v15  possible ?  Thanks.

Not tested , I think it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right, that will not work. Streaming replication requires both servers to have the same major version.